# Moving Two Divs Side-by-Side

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems getting divs onto the same line. My layout idea is attached below, with the idea of having multiple lines of a rectangular/square div duo going down the page, beyond what was shown in this plan. Without the long, rectangular divs, each square was in the planned line.

[An image of several containers stacked in lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOEDY.png)

What my page currently looks like, however, is this, once the rectangles were added (yes, the black div is going off the page):

[An image of several containers on a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erupt.png)

I have purposely removed some of the containers for the boxes on the right side as these are not essential. This is my basic code for the containers:

```css
.1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}

.3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p> text </p>
</div>

<div class="1">
  <p> First Div </p>
</div>

<div class="2">
  <p> Second Div </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p> text </p>
</div>

<div class="3">
  <p Third Div </p>
</div>
```

Moving the position of the divs did not work, so perhaps there is some alternative to using an endless amount of divs?

I am aware that this is extremely messy and probably not the most efficient way to do this. However, each div will eventually be styled and unique. (This was also the only way to fix my original problem, where the squares were not on their own row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.div-1 {
  width:20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.div-2 {
  width:50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.container-1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:end;
}
.div-3 {
  width:60%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.div-4 {
  width:20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.container-2 {
  margin-top:20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.div-5 {
  width:20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.div-6 {
  width:50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.container-3 {
  margin-top:20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:end;
}
.div-7 {
  width:60%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}
.div-8 {
  width:20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-1">
  </div>

  <div class="div-2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-1">
  <div class="div-3">
  </div>

  <div class="div-4">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-2">
  <div class="div-5">
  </div>

  <div class="div-6">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-3">
  <div class="div-7">
  </div>

  <div class="div-8">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}
.box{
    display: flex;
    height: 10rem;
    width: 50%;
    margin: .2rem 16rem;
}
.odd{float: left;}
.odd .left{
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
.even{float: right;}
.even .left{
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
.left{
    width: 25%;
    height: inherit;
}
.right{
    width: 75%;
    height: inherit;
}
.first .left{background-color: #C9E265;}
.first .right{background-color: #7ED957;}

.second .left{background-color: #5DE1E6;}
.second .right{background-color: #00C2CB;}

.third .left{background-color: #FF5757;}
.third .right{background-color: #FF1616;}

.fourth .left{background-color: #CB6CE5;}
.fourth .right{background-color: #8C52FF;}

.fifth .left{background-color: #FFBD58;}
.fifth .right{background-color: #FF904D;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="box odd first">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box even second">
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box odd third">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box even fourth">
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box odd fifth">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: make sure to describe what your proposed solution does so the OP can learn, understand and use your code